# Remove everything before certain character in nested lists (Python)

Tags: python, list

Lets suppose I have a list such as:

[["BLAHBLAH\Desktop","BLAHBLAH\Documents","BLAHBLAH\Vids"],["BLAHBLAH\Pics","BLAHBLAH\Folder","BLAHBLAH\Music"]]

And I wanted an output that would look like

[["Desktop","Documents","Vids"],["Pics","Folder","Music"]]

How would I go about doing so? This is in Python. I know you would have to use rfind with the backslashes but I'm having trouble iterating through the nested lists to maintain that nested list structure

Comment: Can you show us your code that you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use list comprehensions:

```
NestedList = [["BLAHBLAH\Desktop","BLAHBLAH\Documents","BLAHBLAH\Vids"],["BLAHBLAH\Pics","BLAHBLAH\Folder","BLAHBLAH\Music"]]
output = [[os.path.basename(path) for path in li] for li in NestedList]
```

Answer (score 6):

If your filenames are in `myList`, this should do it, and platform-independently too (different OSes use different folder separators, but the os.path module takes care of that for you).

```
import os

[[os.path.basename(x) for x in sublist] for sublist in myList]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
lis=[["BLAHBLAH\Desktop","BLAHBLAH\Documents","BLAHBLAH\Vids"],["BLAHBLAH\Pics","BLAHBLAH\Folder","BLAHBLAH\Music"]]

def stripp(x):
    return x.strip('BLAHBLAH\\')

lis=[list(map(stripp,x)) for x in lis]
print(lis)
```

**output:**

```
[['Desktop', 'Documents', 'Vids'], ['Pics', 'Folder', 'Music']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
from unittest import TestCase
import re


def foo(l):
    result = []
    for i in l:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            result.append(foo(i))
        else:
            result.append(re.sub('.*\\\\', '', i))
    return result


class FooTest(TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        arg = ['DOC\\Desktop', 'BLAH\\FOO', ['BLAH\\MUSIC', 'BLABLA\\TEST']]
        expected = ['Desktop', 'FOO', ['MUSIC', 'TEST']]
        actual = foo(arg)
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of answers is just great. They all work in different contexts. I am just adding this to the list:

```
outer = [["BLAHBLAH\Desktop","BLAHBLAH\Documents","BLAHBLAH\Vids"],
         ["BLAHBLAH\Pics","BLAHBLAH\Folder","BLAHBLAH\Music"]]

purged = [ [ item[ item.find("\\")+1: ]
             for item in inner ]
           for inner in outer ]
```

Kudos (and +1) to

- @Junuxx who was first with the filename solution,
- to @Ashwini Chaudary who got a more general solution if these are not filenames, and
- to @mfusennegger who, I think, is making a joke.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have access to a computer with python atm, but the following should work:

```
List=[["BLAHBLAH\Desktop","BLAHBLAH\Documents","BLAHBLAH\Vids"],["BLAHBLAH\Pics","BLAHBLAH\Folder","BLAHBLAH\Music"]]
final=[]
for varv in List:
    x=varv
    for sub_val in x:
        final.append(sub_val[sub_val.find("/"):])
```